# Scrolling the tableview count label value is changed?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"PickAClassCell";

cell = (PickAClassCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

if (cell == nil)
{
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PickAClassCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}
cell.CountLabel.tag=1000;
return cell;
} 
-(void)PlusButtonSelect :(UIButton *)sender
{
    UILabel *label1 = (UILabel *)[sender.superview viewWithTag:1000];
int count = [label1.text intValue];

        count = count + 1;

        label1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",count];

        NSLog(@"%@",label1);
}
```

This is my code when I click the `PlusButtonSelect` count will be increased. The problem is when my tableview scrolls, the countlabel becomes zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i find an answer,Here `myData` is NsMutableArray. First based on `No of Row` we can take the first Zero's in myData.
 in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
     static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"PickAClassCell";

     cell = (PickAClassCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

      if (cell == nil)
       {
         NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PickAClassCell" owner:self options:nil];
         cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

        }

        cell.CountLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[myData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

        cell.CountLabel.tag=1000;
        [cell.PlusCount addTarget:self action:@selector(PlusButtonSelect :)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        return cell;
}

-(void)PlusButtonSelect :(UIButton *)sender
{

  UILabel *label1 = (UILabel *)[sender.superview viewWithTag:1000];
    NSLog(@"%@",label1);
   int count = [label1.text intValue];
    count = count + 1;
   NSString *Strcount= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",count];
  [myData replaceObjectAtIndex:sender.tag withObject:Strcount];
  [tableview reloadData];

}
```

Same in Minusbutton also.

Answer (score 1):

The data and the reusable cell are not bound together in your case.

You need to create a model (probably a `NSArray`) for all counts at each position.

When you create the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, you need to add the label value from the above array.

Sample code would look like this:

```
if (cell == nil)
{
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PickAClassCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}
cell.CountLabel.tag=1000;
cell.CountLabel.text = [myData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: here what is myData?

Comment: here counts i am giving the static "0", when i click the plus button count value been increased but when i scrolling the tableview value will be change to "0"

Comment: when you click the plus button and you got result with increment, you need to set that value on label in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` so you need to store it somewhere (`NSMutableArray`) and set it as label's text in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: label count i am giving the cell.countlabel.text=@"0";

Comment: first i am giving the all zeros

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  -(void)PlusButtonSelect :(UIButton *)sender
           PickAClassCell *cell = (PickAClassCell *)sender.superview.; // change with your customcell class.
           int count = [cell. CountLabel.text intValue];
          count = count + 1;
    label1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",count];

        }
```

Comment: here how to lable count wil increase?

Comment: try now my updated answer . and ensure that your cell not nil .

Comment: app is crashing, any changes is there in "cellForRowAtIndexPath"?

Comment: - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"PickAClassCell"; cell = (PickAClassCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
  if (cell == nil) { NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PickAClassCell" owner:self options:nil];cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];}cell.CountLabel.tag=1000;
      cell.PlusCount.tag=indexPath.row;[cell.PlusCount addTarget:self action:@selector(PlusButtonSelect :)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];return cell;}

Comment: above is the "cellForRowAtIndexPath" and plusbuttoncode i am using your posted code.

Comment: it is fine and give me crash log also

Comment: give ne crash log here .

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:

Comment: full desrcription of log .

Comment: [RKCardView CountLabel]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1006640e0
2016-12-09 16:13:27.111933 ChkdIn[1069:242635] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[RKCardView CountLabel]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1006640e0'

Comment: when i click the plusbutton

Comment: did you use this line also cell. CountLabel.text = @""; ?

Comment: ya i am using , i think "cellForRowAtIndexPath" any changes code?

Comment: again also crashing.

Comment: this answer is correct but you need check in your code also .

Comment: in cellforRowAtindexpath how to assign the cell.countlabel.text

Comment: as praveen's answer .

Answer (score 0):

This is because when you scroll the tableview, it `deque` the cell for re-usability for better perfomance! I mean tableview resuse your cell so your label gots default value or previous one which you have set.

So, you need to set the label's value in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` everytime before return the `cell`.

You can manage it by taking an array! take an array and add object in it from `PlusButtonSelect` method and show value from it on `label` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method!

Comment: what you want to achieve exactly ?

Comment: how to do in "cellForRowAtIndexPath" and "PlusButtonSelect" can you post the code.

Comment: what you want to achieve means tell me what you want! Tell me your set up like you have label and button in your cell and what you want to do with it!  I am not totally clear with your question

Comment: i have a one label and two button(plush and minus) when i click the plus button lable count want to be increased, i my app label count will increase but my problem is when i scroll the tableview the label count goes to "0".

Comment: and how many cells you have that have this label and buttons for plus and minus ?

Comment: Server it is giving product names, based on product names label count and button will come.

Comment: you need to learn that how `tableview` works. It is large concept to explain here. You need to manage one array that contains label's value and you need to increase or decrease value in array with plus or minus button click and you should display value from your array in label in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` !

Answer (score 0):

problem is due to when you scroll the tableview, reuse the cell for better perfromance due to dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier.so previous or default cell value comes so you need to manage by taking an array.

Comment: either maintain value in array due to reusable the number of cell allocated is visiblecell +1

Answer (score 0):

This is my demo.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface CountModel : NSObject
/** label count */
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger count;
@end

@implementation CountModel
@end

@interface ViewController () <UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
/** save model */
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *modelArrM;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _modelArrM = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        [_modelArrM addObject:[CountModel new]];
    }
    [_tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
}

#pragma mark - TableView dataSource
#pragma mark -TableView --section
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}
#pragma mark -TableView --row
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return _modelArrM.count;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    CountModel *model = _modelArrM[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",model.count];
    cell.textLabel.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tap:)];
    [cell.textLabel addGestureRecognizer:tap];
    return cell;
}
- (void)tap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tap
{
    UILabel *label = (UILabel *)tap.view;
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)label.superview;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [_tableView indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell.superview];
    CountModel *model = _modelArrM[indexPath.row];
    model.count +=1;
    [_tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
}
@end
```

[image: demo]

Comment: i will try it and tell u

Answer (score -1):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"PickAClassCell%@",indexPath];

cell = (PickAClassCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

if (cell == nil)
{
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PickAClassCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}
cell.CountLabel.tag=1000;
return cell;
} 
-(void)PlusButtonSelect :(UIButton *)sender
{
    UILabel *label1 = (UILabel *)[sender.superview viewWithTag:1000];
int count = [label1.text intValue];

        count = count + 1;

        label1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",count];

        NSLog(@"%@",label1);
}
```

you need to change cell identifier

Comment: count value is changes when i scolling.